# ion-fixed not moving smoothly on ios devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I have a page that scrolls, and I want to add a fixed div to the bottom of it in ionic2. I use the ion-fixed, and it works great on android devices staying fixed in the bottom of the page, but on iOS upon scrolling the page, it sort of jumps all the time until get the position. 
I am sure someone working in ionic has forced the same issue.
I have tried to detect platform and to use a css tweak of

```
position: sticky;
```

and it moves smootly, but I am facing another bouncing issue once you are in the end of the page ( the native over-scroll ios behavior, if you continue to scroll the page from the top or the bottom area).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to place a div in the bottom of the page, fixed, the best way to do it in Ionic is to put that div outside of the `ion-content`:

```
<ion-header>
  <!-- ... -->
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <!-- ... -->
</ion-content>

<div class="fixed">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And then use some css style rules to set its position according to your needs:

```
div.fixed { 
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999
}
```

Since it's outside of the content, it will be ignored by Ionic during the scroll event.

Comment: I might try, but the problem here is that I actually have a slide :/ so I want to have it on a specific slide only, so it must goes in between there <ion-slide><ion-slides> .... </ion-slide></ion-slides>

Comment: But yes, I use onslideChanged() to track slide number/name and than I apply the above with *ngIf="slidename" and it works! Thanks, that one really helped to prevent that flicking of the div.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) If you want you can add the following style rules `@keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }` and `.animated.fade-in { animation: fadeIn .5s ease 1; }` and then add that class to your div `<div class="animated fade-in">...</div>`. That will add a nice fade in transition when the div is shown :)

Comment: I might give a try, currently I am anyoed about another thing, and that is if you use [hidden] or *ngClass, and lets say you use some boolean value which you get via onSlideChanged() , in ionic it first slides to the slide and than applies that directive. Let's say in less than one second but still it first slides the slide with a small delay and than the above directives are happened :/ I hope you understand what I want to point out.

Comment: Could you please create another question with that information? I think you could hook on the event when the slide event is starting, but it'd be better if we take a look at it in a different question,

Comment: Thanks, I've posted this one over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311004/ionic-onslidechanged-events-delay