# Ionic onSlideChanged events delay

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using the ion-slides, and I get some events via:

```
(ionSlideDidChange)="onSlideChanged()"
```

I use this function to get the last slide:

```
onSlideChanged() {
this.lastSlide = this.slider.isEnd();
}
```

Than I use this.lastSlide in another directive [hidden] to show or hide some stuff in the next slide.

However there is a slight delay right after the next slide is shown, so after 1 second or less than one second the content is hidden as soon as slider reach to this last slide.

I have tried to use (ionSlideWillChange) instead (ionSlideDidChange) but I it has a delay still.

Comment: Can you show the `html` code?

Comment: What if you use `ionSlideWillChange` like this: `(ionSlideWillChange)="onSlideChanged()"`. That would execute the callback when the slide is starting to change. Please let me know if that works on your end and I'll add an answer with further information.

Comment: Yes, that one does. Actually I was using ionSlideWillChange, but I had some other code which I was using wrong. But, the above function works as expected. Thanks.